# Speed insights not updating after changes

Tags: pagespeed-insights

i updated my website to new picture webp format instead of pngs.
It appears that google insights still is working on previous code, not considering the changes that have been done.
the project is here : https://www.marche-talensac.fr/

If you can see anything wrong, i thank you to have a word in here :)

Regards to you all ^^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are still serving the old image as well as the new image. You will see that your slider is adding the image as a background image via an inline style attribute.

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="https://www.marche-talensac.fr/css/home2.webp">
    <source type="image/png" srcset="https://www.marche-talensac.fr/css/home2.png">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIABAP///wAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="width: 650px; height: 500px; background-image: url(&quot;https://www.marche-talensac.fr/css/home2.png&quot;);" class="homepng">
</picture>
```

If you remove whatever is causing that `style` to be added to your slide it should work as intended.

For clarity remove the code that injects `style="width: 650px; height: 500px; background-image: url(&quot;https://www.marche-talensac.fr/css/home2.png&quot;);"`

Also note that you have only updated the home page slider, all the other images are still served as .jpg files.